# Iteratively Sample from a list Until a Condition is Met - Python

Tags: python-3.x, random

I have a list of values:

```
address_ids = [123,123,123,123,456,789,112,115]
```

From `address_ids` list I want to check what percentage of single value attributing to the whole list.

I am looking at it this way,

```
unique_adres = list(set(address_ids))

save_vals = {}
for i in unique_adres:
    temp_val =  address_ids.count(i)/len(address_ids)
    save_vals[i] = temp_val  
save_vals
>> {456: 0.125, 112: 0.125, 115: 0.125, 789: 0.125, 123: 0.5}
```

123 has 50 percent. I need to have a condition if a single value has more than 50% of the data, then I want to resample with replacement and 8 samples in which a single attribute does not contribute 50% of whole list. Therefore, it will look something like this, (since random smapling, this won't be exactly same) and the idea is making a single attribute  does not contribute 50% of the whole list.

```
>> {456: 0.125, 112: 0.125, 115: 0.125, 789: 0.225, 123: 0.4}
```

OR

```
>> {456: 0.125, 112: 0.225, 115: 0.125, 789: 0.225, 123: 0.3}
```

I tried something like this,

```
from random import choices
for k,v in save_vals.items():
    if v >= 0.50:
        break
    choices_vals = choices(address_ids, k=8)
```

But not sure, how to continuously check my condition with resamples if it doesn't meet the condition `if v >= 0.50:`.

Any help or suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Make your condition a function and use a loop:

```
def needs_improvement(unique_adress):
    save_vals = {}
    for i in unique_adress:
        temp_val =  choices_vals.count(i)/len(choices_vals)
        save_vals[i] = temp_val  
        # this checks if you need to change something
        if temp_val > 0.5:
            return True
   # not necessary as `None` (default value) evaluates to `False`
   return False

while needs_improvement(unique_adres):
    global unique_adres
    unique_adres = choices(address_ids, k=8)
```

Comment: This does not take `123` into account when resampling :(

Answer (score 0):

The `Counter` Class from collections makes it easy:

```
from collections import Counter

address_ids = [123,123,123,123,456,789,112,115]
counter = Counter(address_ids) #{123:4 ,456:1 ,789:1 ,112:1 ,115:1}
common = counter.most_common(1) # [(123,4)]
# where most_common(n) gives the n most common values as a list of tuples

while common[0][1] >= 0.5*len(address_ids):
    #resample
    #recheck common
```

Comment: Can you explain how #recheck common done? Is it 'continue'?

Comment: for a new list "address_ids_2": common  = Counter(address_ids_2).most_comon(1) .... same as above... just update the common variable